# Mazda 323 F is losing power when driving?

Tags: engine, mazda-323f

I've had a Mazda 323f for a few years now with no faults. But now, it's running poorly with a loss of power that then picks up.

I replaced the coil pack and it ran great for a few weeks but then loss of power again.
I swapped: plugs, leads, fuel pump. Still no joy and getting ready to get rid of it.

Someone told me that it was too much air getting in. But you do get a smell fuel so I thought the coil-pack may have gone again but sounds alright when engine is not under pressure.

Comment: someone told me that it too much air getting in but you do get a smell fuel so i thought coil-pack may have gone again but sounds alright when engine is not under pressure.

Comment: Does it have HT leads? Maybe putting the new coil pack on disturbed the possibly faulty HT leads and made it run better for a while.

Comment: its had two coil packs on and still running but when driving you put foot on accelerator and just wont go starts dying now thinking airflow metre.

Comment: it does have ht leads but the coil packs sit on the top of engine and the two sit on top of plugs then the coil packs each have an ht lead that runs to the remaining 2 plugs.

Comment: If it has exactly the same symptoms as the last time which were fixed when you replaced a coil pack, then it seems a bit of a coincidence.  Could you have disturbed something?  Did you replace both coil packs?  I didn't notice the first time that you had replaced the HT leads.

Comment: i replaced both coil packs and new leads run great for a while now its like driving in limp mode but will rev up when stationary.

Comment: The answer to this fault i changed the lambdo sensor and the air flow sensor now runs like a new car again Thanks to - HandyHowie that tried to help with this matter.

Comment: Please for you.  A good result.